# Is there the way to share static resources among pages and user controls in the windows 8.1 store application?

Tags: xaml, resources, windows-store-apps, share

Is there the way to declare static resource once(for example style for some control), and to use that resource in any XAML in the application? 
I want to avoid coping same resource again on every new page or user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Static resource have to be declared at App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources> <Style x:Key="myStyle" ...>...</style></Application.Resources>
```